# Scala play framework Form Validation for numbers

Tags: forms, scala, playframework

I have tried to validate form input only for numbers, I it pop-up an error message

> Read from stdout:
>   D:\PROJECTS\test\SimpleRequest19-DBCon_Session\app\controllers\Prodcuts.scala:24:
>   not found: value number

Here is the helper

```
@helper.inputText(productCreateForm("prosupprice"),'_help -> "",'_label -> "Supplier Price",'_showConstraints -> false)</div>
```

here is the validation function

```
 private val productCreateForm: Form[Product] = Form(
            mapping(

                "proname" -> nonEmptyText,
                "proprice" -> nonEmptyText,
                "prodes" -> nonEmptyText,
                "probrand" -> nonEmptyText,
                "protype" -> nonEmptyText,
                 "prosupplier" -> nonEmptyText,
                 "prosupcode" -> nonEmptyText,
                 "prosupprice"-> number
                )(Product.apply)(Product.unapply)
        )
```

Comment: Not sure if it is intended but you have a typo in "prodcuts" (check error msg). Do you get the same error message if you switch from number to text ? If not, do you get the expected value in your field ?

Comment: What happens if you add min and max values like: number(min = 0, max = 100) ; Do you get the same error msg?

Comment: # PiNg2Eiw#  I have added it , but get the same error,

Comment: if I switch from number to text , it will get the same error, but if i put nonEmptyText its not pop up an error

Comment: LMeyer  Thanks its worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your imports. You should have `play.api.data.Forms._` maybe you have only `play.api.data.Forms.nonEmptyText`